# Localization of Allauth emails

Tags: django, localization, django-allauth, django-i18n

Allauth doc descibe how to customize emails ([here](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#sending-e-mail)).

Now, how can we make Allauth send an email depending of the current language preference?

Answer (score 1):

Setup your own adapter:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'example.MyAdapter'
```

Then:

```
from django.utils import translation

class MyAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def render_mail(self, template_prefix, email, context):
        # Set language, based on `email`, or `self.request.session`, or
        # whatever fits your project
        #
        # TODO: insert your logic here
        lang = 'nl'  

        with translation.override(lang):
             return super().render_mail(template_prefix, email, context)
```